# Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\pagename]

Tags: php, laravel

Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\pagename].
I have given this

Comment: I`m not able to define my controller properly can anyone help.

Comment: Please add more details in the question like your code and what have you tried. Thank you.

Comment: Please run this `php artisan route:list` and show the output screenshot,also if you can share you're web.php file ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the controller@method. You must have to use method name after controller you used.

```
Route::get('user/profile', 'UserProfileController@show')->name('profile');
```